# What is the Signing Credential in IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, identityserver4

We are in the process of implementing Identity Server 4 with our .NET Core web app.

I went trough the Identity Server documentation. When configuring the Identity server (using DI) there is the line:

```
.AddTemporarySigningCredential
```

I'm trying to understand what this Signing credential is but couldn't figure out. Therefore I don't know if it's ok to use the built in temporary, or if I should provide a different one.

My question is, what is a signing credential and how should I use it?

In the Identity server documentation this is the definition:

> Adds a signing key service that provides the specified key material to
>   the various token creation/validation services. You can pass in either
>   an X509Certificate2, a SigningCredential or a reference to a
>   certificate from the certificate store.

So it seems important :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The Authorization Server will sign tokens with a key. Resource Server(s) should verify that the token's integrity with a key. Together they form a (usually asymmetric, e.g. public/private) key (pair). By default IdentityServer will publish the public key for verifying tokens via the `/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint.

For development scenarios, you typically want to skip the fuss of properly managing secrets like said keys (which is *really* important to do properly in production!). For these development scenarios you have the option of using adhoc solutions like `AddTemporarySigningCredential`, which was used for **.NET Core 1.x**.

With **.NET Core 2.x** this will [change](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1057) and you will need the `AddDeveloperSigningCredential()` extension method.

That answers the question of *what it is*. On how to use it: you simply call the method you need depending on your .NET Core version inside the `ConfigureServices(...)` method of your application's `Startup` class.

Apart from that you don't need to do anything special, except of course take care that you use a proper key pair in production.

See also the docs on [Cryptography, Keys and HTTPS](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html) and [the bit on Configuring Services for Keys](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html?highlight=x509#configuring-services). From the latter document, here's a relevant alternative for production cases:

> - `AddSigningCredential`
>
>   Adds a signing key service that provides the specified key material to the various token creation/validation services. You can pass in either an `X509Certificate2`, a `SigningCredential` or a reference to a certificate from the certificate store.

Comment: thanks. I read the breaking changes doc. I didn't understand what should I use in production?

Comment: Oh right! You can use `AddSigningCredential(...)`, see [these docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/startup.html?highlight=x509#configuring-services). Updated my answer a bit.

Comment: It's probably because I don't understand everything as I should. How do I create a key for AddSigningCredential?

Comment: Creating and managing certificates (especially ones like x509 certs) is a whole topic on its own. The IdentityServer docs seem vague about that topic, perhaps purposely so (because it's seen as a separate concern). I'm no expert either, but I think you can use a tool of your choice to create a self-signed x509 certificate, because all that matters is that you get a good pub/private key pair with enough entropy.

Comment: @Jeroen, what did you mean with "By default IdentityServer will publish the public key for verifying tokens on the /.well-known/openid-configuration endpoint."? For me this route dosen't show this information.

Comment: @CassioFariasMachado Hmmm weird. I was talking about [the Discovery Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/discovery.html), which IIRC should be enabled by default. The response should be similar to [the  demo server response](https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration). Ifou're not getting that endpoint I suggest asking a new question with steps to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: @Jeroen, It's my mistake, I have access to this too. I was trying to authorize a Node api by the Identity Server and I was with problems to authorize my aplication to validate the tokens. For resume, I did this using the route `/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` for get public key and validate the tokens.